# Apply list of functions to maybe value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, ramda-fantasy

I'm using `ramda-fantasy` for the monads. I have a string inside a maybe and a some functions that will perform regex matches on a string and return a `Maybe String`.

How do I map the maybe to apply all of the functions and concatenate the result?

I have

```
const fieldRetrievers = [ 
  getAddress,
  getName,
  getPhone, 
]

const text = Maybe.of("a text")

// I want to define
// List (String -> Maybe String) -> Maybe String -> Maybe String
function getInfo(retrievers, maybeText) {...}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You want to get the phone from the name part of the address part of the string?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`composeK`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#composeK), the function composition over monadic structures ("kleisli arrows").

Basically, your resulting function is supposed to repeatedly [`chain`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) onto the input:

```
text.chain(getAddress).chain(getName).chain(getPhone)
```

which you could implement using a [`reduce`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#reduce) over your array of functions:

```
R.reduce((m, f) => m.chain(f), text, fieldRetrievers)
```

so you'd write

```
const getInfo = R.flip(R.reduce(R.flip(R.chain)))
```

Comment: Nice. But if one of the functions returns `Nothing` the entire result would be `Nothing`. I would like to ignore all `Nothing`s.

Comment: What do you mean, ignore? What else could you return if not `Nothing`? Please provide some example functions with example input and the expected output in your question.

Comment: Imagine I have the string `"Name: John | Address: Apple Street"`. In this example, `getName` would return `Just "John"`, getAddress would return `Just "Apple Street"` and getPhone would return `Nothing`. 
My goal is to run all of these functions against the original string and concatenate the results, ignoring the `Nothing`s. 
In the example I gave, the desired output would be `"John, Apple Street"`.

Is there a concise way to do that?

Comment: Please put that example in your question, I'll post another answer.